# Set Object Location Visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

I made some code to move a player one pixel in Visual basic, I'm not trying to ask you guys to convert code for me, but to help me find code to do the below but in Visual C++

Visual Basic Code:

```
steve.Location = New Point(steve.Location.X, steve.Location.Y - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to build a program with a window. The tutorial linked below does that and includes a simple little animation of a ball.

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: I have alrety done that... Using Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
steve->Location = gcnew Point(steve->Location.X, steve->Location.Y - 1);
```

because the `Form` object `steve` is from a **reference class**, not a value class. Same for `Point()`, you must use `gcnew` instead of `New`.